# CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE with Type and Table Dependencies

Tags: oracle, oop, plsql

Before submitting this question I've checked the Oracle docs about this subject:
[Using CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE with Type and Table Dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjmng.htm#CHDBAEHJ)

but still don't get my error solved.

I've created some object types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SchoolMember AS OBJECT (
    ...
) NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember (
   ...
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Curse AS OBJECT (
   ...
   refTeacher REF Teacher,
   ...
);
/
```

Let's say I want to modify the Teacher object type adding a constructor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember (
   ...
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Teacher(...) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Teacher AS
...
END;
/
```

I get the  **ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents** because the Teacher type is used in the Curse object type itself.

Where should I place the FORCE option when modifiying an inherited object type (Teacher in this case)?
I've tried several ways, but none of them working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher FORCE UNDER SchoolMember
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember FORCE
```

But the ORA-02303 error is still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot exactly reproduce your issue.

**Original Objects**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SchoolMember AS OBJECT (a number) NOT FINAL;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember (b number);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Curse AS OBJECT (refTeacher REF Teacher);
  2  /

Type created.
```

**Create without FORCE fails**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember (
  2     b number,
  3     CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Teacher RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  4  );
  5  /
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember (
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents
```

**Create with FORCE works**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher FORCE UNDER SchoolMember (
  2     b number,
  3     CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Teacher RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.
```

---

**Update**

The `FORCE` option for `CREATE TYPE` was added in 11gR2.  You can see it in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS1619) 11gR2 syntax diagram, but not in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_type.htm#sthref2960) 11gR1 diagram.

In your case, you will need to drop the type before you recreate it.

```
SQL> DROP TYPE Teacher VALIDATE;

Type dropped.
```

Comment: There's no table involved. You did not get the  ORA-02303 error because there was a compilation error when you created the object type Curse (it has just one attribute, you wrote a comma in excess).

Comment: Woops, sorry about that.  I updated my example, and it works fine with your `FORCE` syntax.

Comment: It does not work for me. I'm using Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

Drop the type with force option and execute your code. It will work

```
DROP TYPE Teacher VALIDATE FORCE;

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Teacher UNDER SchoolMember (
       b number,
       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Teacher RETURN SELF AS RESULT
    );
```

Type created.

Comment: Be very careful using `FORCE` with `DROP TYPE`, it may alter tables and lose data!